# PHP character remove in string

Tags: php, string, text

hello i have a variable that has the text below:

```
<p>Not sure exactly which property you want to extract, but I assume it's the 'question_answers_url'.</p>

<pre><code>$answersArray = Array();
for($i=0;$i&lt;count($jsonArray['questions']);$i++){
    //assuming it is the 'question_answers_url' property that you want
    array_push($answersArray,$jsonArray['questions'][$i]['question_answers_url']);
}
</code></pre>

<p>Ought to do it.</p>
```

how can i get only the text that is between `<p>TEXT_I_WANT</p>` and trash everything else.

Comment: I don't see `<p>TEXT_I_WANT</p>` anywhere in your text.  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: what do you mean? i want the text that is between p's

Comment: i've tried splitting the text into chars and then trying to figure out if it's <p keep text if read </p stop reading but i think there must be a better way

Comment: Yup, there is a better way.  Start by learning how to use [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and related bits of DOMDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/is",$text,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($maches as $match){
  echo $match[1];
}
```

Untested !!

Updated!

Comment: Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'p' in.....                         and Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in....